# Javascript radio button not copying fields when clicked

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have a script that is supposed to copy once set of form fields to another when  a radio button is checked. It works on Safari, firefox (mac) but not on FF (PC) or IE.

```
function checkFirstDirAddrs() { 
var i;
//checking which radio button selected
for ( i = 0;  i < FirstCorpDirAddOption.length; i++) {

if (FirstCorpDirAddOption[i].checked == true) {

    switch(i)
    {
        case 0:
        document.getElementById("First_Corp_Director_Address1").value =  document.getElementById("Corp_Address1").value;
        document.getElementById("First_Corp_Director_Address2").value = document.getElementById("Corp_Address2").value;
        document.getElementById("First_Corp_Director_City").value = document.getElementById("Corp_City").value;     
        document.getElementById("First_Corp_Director_Postal").value = document.getElementById("Corp_Postal").value; 
        break

        case 1:
        document.getElementById("First_Corp_Director_Address1").value = '';
        document.getElementById("First_Corp_Director_Address2").value = '';
        document.getElementById("First_Corp_Director_City").value = '';         
        document.getElementById("First_Corp_Director_Postal").value = '';
        break
     }

   }
 }

}
```

The html....

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10"><strong>*Director Address</strong></div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
     <div class="radio">
        <label> 
            <input name="FirstCorpDirAddOption" id="FirstCorpDirAddOption" type="radio" value="Same as Corporate Address" onClick="checkFirstDirAddrs();">
            Same as Corporate Address<br>          
        </label>
        <label>
            <input name="FirstCorpDirAddOption" id="FirstCorpDirAddOption" type="radio" value="Other" onClick="checkFirstDirAddrs();">
            Other <em>(provided below)</em> 
        </label>
        </div>
    </div>            
 </div>

  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="First_Corp_Director_Address1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">*Address:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="First_Corp_Director_Address1" name="First_Corp_Director_Address1" maxlength="80"> 
        </div>
    </div>               
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="First_Corp_Director_Address2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address 2:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="First_Corp_Director_Address2" name="First_Corp_Director_Address2" maxlength="80">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="First_Corp_Director_City" class="col-sm-2 control-label">*City:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="First_Corp_Director_City" name="First_Corp_Director_City" maxlength="50"> 
        </div>
    </div>       

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="First_Corp_Director_Postal" class="col-sm-2 control-label">*Postal/Zip:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="First_Corp_Director_Postal" id="First_Corp_Director_Postal" maxlength="7">
            <span class="help-block">(enter NA if not from Canada/USA)</span> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

If anyone can shed some more light on the issue that would be great. It works fine on most Mac based browsers I tested on and throws no errors in the Console of dev tools.

Comment: You have an invalid duplicate ID of: "FirstCorpDirAddOption" on your radio buttons.

Comment: Ok but if I give each radio option a separate ID then I get errors because my script can no longer find the proper selector:

if (FirstCorpDirAddOption[i].checked == true)

Comment: Either access the elements by their shared name, or use a CSS class to "group" them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the duplicate IDs as they are causing you trouble.

You have 3 options if you get rid of the duplicate IDs to still have a 'hook' that JavaScript can use to access the elements.

- Option 1: access the elements by **name**
- Option 2: access the elements by a new CSS **class** name
- Option 3: access the elements by some other "loosely defined" method

For simplicity I'm going to recommend #1, but #2 is just as good.

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="FirstCorpDirAddOption" value="Same as Corporate Address" onclick="checkFirstDirAddrs();"/>
            Same as Corporate Address
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="FirstCorpDirAddOption" value="Other" onclick="checkFirstDirAddrs();"/>
            Other <em>(provided below)</em> 
  </label>
</div>
```

Now the JavaScript to access the input(s):

```
function checkFirstDirAddrs(){
  var i;
  //checking which radio button selected
  var firstCorpDirOptions = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="FirstCorpDirAddOption"]');
  for(i=0;i<firstCorpDirOptions.length;i++){
    if(firstCorpDirOptions[i].checked == true){
      //...
```

Comment: 'First_Corp_Director_Address1' is undefined is error from console in IE

Comment: Do you still have that ID on the address field?... And if so, does the case and spelling match exactly? As long as there's no duplicate this should work in IE11.

Comment: no duplicate and the id is there
            <label for="First_Corp_Director_Address1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">*Address:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="First_Corp_Director_Address1" name="First_Corp_Director_Address1" maxlength="80"> 
         </div>
        </div>

Comment: By any chance do you have a full copy of the revised JS/HTML?... I think we'd need to see that to determine the new issue.

Comment: Ok you can see it here:
https://www.ontariobusinesscentral.ca/secure/biz-artcorp-form.asp - its the section under First Corporate Director

Comment: on line 702 of ontarioIncorpValidate.js you need a prefix on that line and the ones following it of: `document.form1.` to indicate that you are looking for those elements inside of a form.

Answer (score 1):

As I know there is no standard for treating same ids in one document via global variable.

It's good to know about reference between ids and global variable they initialize. But God please, do not use it. You can use any selector or create different ids instead of trying to get ids with 'FirstCorpDirAddOption'. Just like this, for example:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.radio input')
```

Just check what you get via global variable:

Here is Chrome
[image: Here is Chrome]
Here is FF
[image: Here is FF]

They are different. Thus you can't use same code for them.